# Display barchart based on selected item from dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-visualization

I'm currently working with barcharts on a website which has been developed using ASP and C#. The barchart has been developed using [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart). The value to the barchart is retrieved from a DB. I can manage to display the barchart without a problem with the correct value. Now the client requires a drop-down list which users can select items from. A barchart should get displayed according to the selected item.

So for example If the user selected **Retail** A graph containing that data should get displayed on the page.

To put the graph together my code is below;

```
private void BindChart()
{
    DataTable dsChartData = new DataTable();
    StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        dsChartData = GetChartData();

        strScript.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>  
                google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']}); </script>  

                <script type='text/javascript'>  

                function drawChart() {         
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
                ['Course', 'Progression'],");

        foreach (DataRow row in dsChartData.Rows)
        {
            strScript.Append("['" + row["Course"] + "'," + row["Progression"] + "],");
        }
        strScript.Remove(strScript.Length - 1, 1);
        strScript.Append("]);");

        strScript.Append(@" var options = {     
                                hAxis: {
                                viewWindow: {
                                min: 0,
                                max: 100
                                },
                                ticks: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100],
                                },
                                title: 'My Progression (%)'      
                                };   ");

        strScript.Append(@"var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barchart'));          
                            chart.draw(data, options);        
                            }    
                        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);  
                        ");
        strScript.Append(" </script>");

        ltScripts.Text = strScript.ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        dsChartData.Dispose();
        strScript.Clear();
    }
}
```

To get the values from DB my code is as follows;

```
private DataTable GetChartData()
{
    string UsrName = User.Identity.Name;
    DataSet dt = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Common.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Progression,Course FROM Messages where UserName=@UserName"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    SqlParameter para2 = new SqlParameter("UserName", UsrName);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(para2);
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
                    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Course";
                    DropDownList1.DataBind();
                }
            }
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select your course"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    return dt.Tables[0];
}
```

If I use the code below it works for the first time but after that it doesn't populate the chart. `BindChart1` exactly the same as `BindChart`. It just gets `document.getElementById('barchart1')` instead of `document.getElementById('barchart')`

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        BindChart1()
    }
    else{
        BindChart();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for all your help and support.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing it manually separately - have you looked at the dashboard controls? They allow you to have a graph and table or sliders etc to dynamically change the data visualisation all from the client side rather than doing server postbacks to generate the javascript.

Here's the page from the manual: [google charts api link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did have a look at this before but the issue I have is that all the barcharts will contain different data from DB. So I'm not sure if the approach you suggested would be the best one.

Comment: Hmm I see, have you checked console for javascript errors? Also are you applying your binddata methods inside if(!isPostBack)? If not it could just be re-applying your default view each time

Comment: I've checked for JS errors in the console and don't seem to have any and I am also applying my `BindData()` methods inside `if(!isPostBack)`

Comment: when I select an item it will load the chart but the drop-down list will automatically set the `SelectedIndex` to 0 :/